# User created in migration does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have a system user that I've created in a data migration:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_system_user(apps, schema_editor):
    system_user = User.objects.get_or_create(username="system")[0]
    system_user.set_password("system")
    system_user.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0021_prev_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_system_user)
    ]
```

I ran `python manage.py migrate` and the migration seemed to run normally. If I drop into the shell, the user exists as expected.  However, when I run my test suite, I get an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/admin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/admin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/admin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/user/admin_api/scheduler/tests/test_tasks.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scheduler.tasks import (floor_datetime_to_minutes, save_task_details,
  File "/home/user/admin_api/scheduler/tasks.py", line 48, in <module>
    SYSTEM_USER = User.objects.get(username='system')
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/admin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/admin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Django 1.10, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests always start with an empty database; it looks like your tasks.py is getting imported before the migration that creates the default user has had a chance to run.

However you should not be doing things like queries at module level, for precisely this reason. Move that line in tasks.py into a function and call it when it is needed.

Comment: Derp.  I knew that.  Thanks!